# Installing QGIS plugin from zipfile to custom menu not default menu location

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

How do I install the QGIS plugins from a zip file into the custom menu instead of into the default menu provided in the zip?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Such questions are too broad and you can find many tutorials in google.

Comment: You can't, the plugin contains the information about which menu it should install to. You would need to unpack and edit the plugin and then reinstall it